# Weird issue with Vue / Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pointers, reference

I honestly don't even know how to search for this question (what search param to write) but either way its bit weird issue and I am desperate for help.

So I am trying to do something simple, event sends **"form-change"** and when it does, we set new value in **"this.data"** object. Fairly simple. I don't expect **this.data** to be reactive I just want to update it.

```
// Find our data object which we want to update/change
if (form.field.includes('.')) {

    let find = form.field.split('.'), level = this.data;
    for (let index = 0; index < find.length; index++) {

        if (level[find[index]] !== undefined) {

            level = level[find[index]];

        } else {

            level = undefined;

        }

    }

    if (level !== undefined)
        level = setFieldData();

}
```

This is fairly simple, we have name of field **"inspect.book"** and when update comes (Event) we just use dots to split into multi tree and update **"this.data.inspect.book"** to new value. But it does not work. Value does not change.

But the value from actual this.data.inspect.book comes out just fine using:

```
console.log(level);
```

However, if I do this:

```
this.data[ form.field.split( '.' )[ 0 ] ][ form.field.split( '.' )[ 1 ] ] = setFieldData();
```

It works fine. So "reference" to variable does not work... how is this possible? Looks like a bug in javascript or is it something with vue/reactivity?

Does anyone have better idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to update form data using to notation ?

i would do something like that :

```
_update(fieldName, value) {
            // We split segments using dot notation (.)
            let segments = fieldName.split(".");

            // We get the last one
            let lastSegment = segments.pop();

            // We start with this.data as root
            let current = this.data

            if(current) {
                // We update current by going down each segment
                segments.forEach((segment) => {
                    current = current[segment];
                });

                // We update the last segment once we are down the correct depth
                current[lastSegment] = val;
            }
        },
```

if i take your example :

```
if (form.field.includes('.')) {

    let find = form.field.split('.'), level = this.data;
    for (let index = 0; index < find.length - 1; index++) {

        if (level[find[index]] !== undefined) {

            level = level[find[index]];

        } else {

            level = undefined;

        }

    }

    if (level !== undefined)
        level[find.pop()] = setFieldData();

}
```

i replaced `find.length` by `find.length - 1`
and replaced `level = setFieldData()` by `level[find.pop()] = setFieldData()`

you should update the property of the object, without actually overriding the value,
because if you override the value, the original value will not get updated.

Comment: I am trying something like you've wrote, just bit differently. The problem is that current[segment] = "New Value" will not set "New Value". Instead it will still show "Old Value" after setting.

Comment: I think it's because you need to stop before the last segment, you cant do lastSegment = val but previousSegment[lastSegment] = val

Comment: I will try thanks!!! This js fiddle I made actually shows my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/e8jgoaL3/1/ (3 alerts, 2nd should be "no") I think I'm messing up some basics of JS programming but after really long time I'm still exploring :P

Comment: Sorry for spam, but this was actually my problem... I tried to "modify" / change actual value while I was supposed to do how you fixed my issue above... Amazing... After almost 16 years of coding I never hit such banal issue. Thank you @Lk77 !!!!